# BadImageFormatException disposing

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, dispose

I'm running on X64

here is my code:

```
 ColorFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(new IntPtr(-1), IntPtr.Zero, 0x04, 0, _byteCount, null);
 ViewerImageData = MapViewOfFile(ColorFileMapping, 0xF001F, 0, 0, _byteCount);
```

however when I try to dispose of this IntPtr i get a BadImageFormatException

can you please explain why?

```
public void Dispose()
 {              
     Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ViewerImageData); //here i get the exception
     Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ColorFileMapping);
 }
```

Comment: i'm not mixing. i'm working X64 all the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It you call to `MapViewOfFile` is actually a call to the Windows API function [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then you should not treat it as a **HGLOBAL**. It's pointer to an area of memory, and when you've finished with it you need to call [UnmapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also, the `HANDLE` you get back from [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should be closed by calling [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: it says here to use http://blog.tedd.no/2011/07/28/unsafe-kernel32-mapped-memory-bitmap-wpf/  InteropBitmap.Invalidate();

Comment: @Androidy - it doesn't!!! If you look at the `Dispose` method in his code he's calling UnmapViewOfFile and CloseHandle.